# Cannot deploy to heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

**Can someone help me regarding this problem. I can run this code by typing npm start but can I run it by any other option like nodemon src/server.js since I want to deploy it to heroku. here is my packag.json**

```
    {
      "name": "quickstartnodejs",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "a quick start for node.js project",
      "main": "server.js",
      "scripts": {
        "start": "nodemon --exec babel-node src/server.js"
      },
      "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "git+https://github.com/haryphamhust/quickStartNodeJSProject.git"
      },
      "keywords": [
        "nodejs",
        "mysql"
      ],
      "author": "Hary Pham",
      "license": "ISC",
      "bugs": {
        "url": "https://github.com/haryphamhust/quickStartNodeJSProject/issues"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": "14.15.1"
      },
      "homepage": "https://github.com/haryphamhust/quickStartNodeJSProject#readme",
      "dependencies": {
        "absorb": "^1.0.1",
        "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
        "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
        "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
        "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
        "ejs": "^3.1.2",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "express-fileupload": "^1.2.1",
        "express-session": "^1.17.2",
        "express-validator": "^6.12.0",
        "generate-password": "^1.6.0",
        "multer": "^1.4.2",
        "mysql": "^2.18.1",
        "nodemailer": "^6.6.2",
        "passport": "^0.4.1",
        "passport-local": "^1.0.0"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.14.8",
        "@babel/node": "^7.14.7",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.8",
        "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
        "nodemon": "^2.0.3"
      }
    }
```

does anyone have an idea

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a Procfile. Create a new file in your app root directory and call it Procfile (no dots or extentions). Populate it with the following:

```
web: node ./src/server.js
```

Check out the docs here:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs